# How to combine stmt and multi query in MySqli & PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to reset the id increment of my table (collections). I'm using mysqli_multi_query to do so. However, when I try to carry out the next query, the stmt fails to bind.

I've tried to use the multi query as a stmt, but to no success. I've never used mysqli_multi_query before.

```php
$sql = "SET  @num := 0; ";
    $sql .= "UPDATE collections SET id = @num := (@num+1);";
    $sql .= "ALTER TABLE collections AUTO_INCREMENT =1;";
    mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql);

    // table is incremented correctly
    unset($sql);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM collections"; //
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo "sqlError";
        exit();
    } else { //....
```

Comment: And the error message is ...? You do set `id` to 1 on all rows? If `id` is the auto increment then this makes no sense (to me).